# Shapes are not drawn on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I am new to html5. I have written a small code that add a rectangle on canvas.  When I double click on canvas, some how it is not working can any one guide me where am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
function init() {
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    canvas2.ondblclick = doubleclickhandler;

}
function doubleclickhandler (){
      var canv = document.getElementById("canvas2");
      var ctx = canv.getContext("2d"); 
      ctx.fillStyle = "rbga(0,200,0,1)" ;
      ctx.fillRect = (36,10,22,22);
}
</script>
<style>
#div2
{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;

}
</style>
<body onLoad="init()">
 <div id= "div2">
 <canvas id="canvas2" width="100" height="150" ></canvas>          
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please define "it is not working".

Comment: @Howard the rectangle is not add on double click

Comment: Note that using `onload` attribute—mixing your HTML with your JavaScript—is not a best practice. You should instead either put your `<script>` block at the end of your body, or use JavaScript to invoke itself when the page is loaded, e.g. `window.onload=function(){ /* your code here */ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ctx.fillRect = (36,10,22,22)` is an assignment, while `ctx.fillRect` is usually a method, not an attribute. You need to call it like a function:

```
ctx.fillRect(36, 10, 22, 22);
```

Comment: @Phrogz I was accepting it but it say "you can accept after 6 minutes :)"

Answer (score 3):

`fillRect` is a function and not a property. You have to call it. AFAIK that's your only mistake.

```
<script>
function init() {
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    canvas2.ondblclick = doubleclickhandler;

}
function doubleclickhandler (){
      var canv = document.getElementById("canvas2");
      var ctx = canv.getContext("2d"); 
      ctx.fillStyle = "rbga(0,200,0,1)" ;
      ctx.fillRect(36,10,22,22);
}
</script>
<style>
#div2
{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;

}
</style>
<body onLoad="init()">
 <div id= "div2">
 <canvas id="canvas2" width="100" height="150" ></canvas>          
 </div>
</body>
```